# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<PaymentData>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I will do a listing with FutureBuilder, but `print(snapshot.error);` When I do **('List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>')** I get an error, I cannot list. How can I solve this problem?

```
FutureBuilder<List<PaymentData>>(
  future: paymentGetList(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  print(snapshot.error);
  var data = snapshot.data;
  
  if (data == null) {
    return const Text('No Data');
  } else {
    return const Text('Yes Data');
  }}),
```

PaymentService.dart

```
Future<List<PaymentData>> paymentGetList(BuildContext context) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  dynamic responseData;
  String token = await getToken();
  final paymentListApiUrl = Uri.parse(
      apiUrlKey + preferences.getString('apiUrl').toString() + paymentListUrl);

try {

  final response = await http.post(paymentListApiUrl, headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }, body: {
      'filters': '',
      'params': '',
      'limit': '10',
      'offset': '0',
      'sorting': ''
    });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var jsonArray = jsonData['data'];
    List<PaymentData> jsonResult =
        (jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as List)
            .map((e) => PaymentData.fromMap(e))
            .toList();
    responseData = jsonArray;
  }

} catch (e) {

  print("Error:  $e");

}

  return responseData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FutureBuilder<List<PaymentData>>(
  future: paymentGetList(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {  //important to see if your future has finished loading
   if (snapshot.error) {
    print(snapshot.error);
    return const Text('No Data because of error');
    } 
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      print(snapshot.data);
      var data = snapshot.data;
      return const Text('Yes Data');
    }
    else {
     return const Text('No Data');
    }
  }
 
}),
```

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: does the console show anything?

Comment: It should list data var but it shows null.

Comment: at what poitnt is it logging null? The point is to trace out the code. if it's inside the snapshot.error loop, what is the print statement log? Anything after that means PaymentService.dart has error somewhere or your http call is not returning what you expect

Comment: Data is coming in successfully. Even when I print on payment_service, my data is coming. But I can't perform operations on FutureBuilder.